# How do I open a file named .txt with CreateFile() API function?

Tags: string, winapi, unicode, filenames, createfile

Code points of some Unicode characters (like ) consume more than 2-bytes. How do I use Win32 API functions like `CreateFile()` with these characters?

**WinBase.h**

```
WINBASEAPI
__out
HANDLE
WINAPI
CreateFileA(
    __in     LPCSTR lpFileName,
    __in     DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    __in     DWORD dwShareMode,
    __in_opt LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    __in     DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    __in     DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    __in_opt HANDLE hTemplateFile
    );
WINBASEAPI
__out
HANDLE
WINAPI
CreateFileW(
    __in     LPCWSTR lpFileName,
    __in     DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    __in     DWORD dwShareMode,
    __in_opt LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    __in     DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    __in     DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    __in_opt HANDLE hTemplateFile
    );
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateFile  CreateFileW
#else
#define CreateFile  CreateFileA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

LPCSTR and LPCWSTR are define in **WinNT.h** as:

```
typedef __nullterminated CONST CHAR *LPCSTR, *PCSTR;
typedef __nullterminated CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR, *PCWSTR;
```

`CHAR` and `WCHAR` is defined in **WinNT.h** as:

```
typedef char CHAR;
#ifndef _MAC
typedef wchar_t WCHAR;    // wc,   16-bit UNICODE character
#else
// some Macintosh compilers don't define wchar_t in a convenient location, or define it as a char
typedef unsigned short WCHAR;    // wc,   16-bit UNICODE character
#endif
```

`CreateFileA()` accepts `LPCSTR` file names, which are stored in 8-bit `char` array internally.
`CreateFileW()` accepts `LPCWSTR` file names, which are stored in 16-bit `wchar_t` array internally.

I have created a file in the position *C:\.txt*. It looks like it is not possible to open this file using `CreateFile()`, because it contains the character  whose Unicode code point is 0x24B62 which doesn't fit even in a WCHAR array cell.

But that file exists in my harddisk and Windows manages it normally. How do I open this file by a Win32 API function, like Windows does internally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such characters are represented by [UTF-16 surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF). It takes two wide character elements to represent that code point. So, you just need to call `CreateFile` passing the necessary surrogate pair. And naturally you need to use the wide variant of `CreateFile`.

Presumably you won't be hard-coding such a filename in your code. In which case you'll be getting it from a file dialog, `FindFirstFile`, etc. And those APIs will give you the appropriate UTF-16 encoded buffer for the file.

Comment: Do you mean that `CreateFile()` always takes UTF-16 encoded strings, but since UTF-16 encoding of most commonly used strings are simply themselves, we don't feel this, and it comes into action in case of passing strings that contain these complex characters?

Comment: UTF-16 encoding is a variable width encoding. Some code points are coded with one character unit, some with two character units. Read around the topic of surrogate pairs. I gave you a wikipedia link.

Comment: I read your link. I want to learn the behavior of `CreateFileW()`. Does it **always** take `lpFileName` parameter in UTF-16 encoded form? Or do I have to switch into this mode by doing something first?

Comment: Yes, `CreateFileW` receives UTF-16 encoded filename. That's the Windows convention. The `W` suffix functions work with UTF-16 data. In fact Windows is natively a UTF-16 system.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my issue with Python Win32file.CreateFile also.