# Python win32file.CreateFile with UniCode Character

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, pywin32, createfile

When trying to access a file with a Russian unicode character using `win32file.CreateFile()`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-utf8.py", line 36, in <module>
    None )
pywintypes.error: (123, 'CreateFile', 'The filename, directory name, or volume l
abel syntax is incorrect.')
```

Here's the code. I'm using Python 2.7. I verify that I can open it with regular Python 'open':

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# We need the line above to tell Python interpreter to use UTF8. 
# You must save this file with UTF8 encoding.
'''
Testing UTF8 Encoding
'''
import win32file
import os, sys

path = u'C:\\TempRandom\\utf8-1\\boo\\hi это русский end - Copy.txt'
# Clean path when printing since Windows terminal only supports ASCII:
print("Path: " + path.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace'))
# Test that you can open it with normal Python open:
normal_fp = open (path, mode='r')
normal_fp.close()

fileH = win32file.CreateFile( path, win32file.GENERIC_READ, \
                            win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32file.FILE_SHARE_WRITE, \
                            None, # No special security requirements \
                            win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, # expect the file to exist. \
                            0, # Not creating, so attributes dont matter. \ 
                            None ) # No template file       
result, msg =  win32file.ReadFile(fileH, 1000, None)
print("File Content >>")
print(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `CreateFileW` and not `CreateFile`:
`fileH = win32file.CreateFileW`

Ironically, the [documentation for `CreateFile`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32file__CreateFile_meth.html) says it supports PyUnicode strings, but the underlying Windows function does not, unless you use `CreateFileW`. `CreateFileW` supports wide characters for unicode.

**Thanks to this post discussing the C version of `CreateFile`:**
[How do I open a file named 𤭢.txt with CreateFile() API function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644150/how-do-i-open-a-file-named-txt-with-createfile-api-function)